# Highlight part of the text within an option tag

Tags: html, css, html-select, prototypejs

I have been asked to produce a select list that looks like this:

[image]

The problem I'm having is how to set a different colour for the asterisk and the text.  I've tried to wrap the asterisk in various inline HTML tags, but it seems that any HTML is stripped out.

HTML:

```
<select id="select-list">
    <option value='1'><em>*</em>A value</option>
    <option value='2'><span>*</span>Another value</option>
</select>
```

Output the rendered HTML:

```
$('select-list').select('option').each(function(element) {
   console.log($(element).innerHTML);
});
```

> *A value
>
> *Another value

Can anyone suggest a technique for doing this?  It's OK to use JavaScript (prototype), but I do not want to replace the select element.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejUvt/2/

**Edit:**  I have considered removing the asterisk from the text and using a background image instead, but I'm not sure if this would be a bad thing in terms of accessibility for users with screen-readers and similar text-based setups?  Further down the form there is a message saying that `* = required`, so would it be confusing that the select did not seem to be marked with an asterisk?

Comment: Seeing your using prototype/jscript could you not just create/find something that looks like a drop down.

Comment: I can, and will for screen based browsers that don't support CSS styling of select elements. So, IE < 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `option` tags cannot contain HTML markup, as per [this W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/option.html). Only [normal character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#normal-character-data) is permitted inside them.

A workaround: using a background image (of an asterisk, or whatever) (positioned left) and add left padding to the `option` element; though this may work in all browsers.